# Nodejs express catch a call to a public file on the server

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building a site in node.js express and Angularjs. 
The whole site is static and I serve it through public like so:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'),{}));
```

How can I catch in express a call to a specific page?

I tried this:

```
app.all("/app",multipart,function(req, res, next){
    console.log("Checking if the user is logged");        
});
```

The `/app` is a static html page that's in the `public` directory, but my breakpoint on the console.log never gets reached. 
I'm trying to block access to certain files in the static directory basically. There might be an other better way. I'm open.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an example for showing how I could manage this scenario.

The directory tree of the project, where **public directory** contains the public assets and inside there is a **protected directory** for storing the protected asssets.

```
├── app.js
└── public
    ├── index.html
    └── protected
        └── app.html
```

In the `app.js` file I am using a middleware `app.use('/protected/*', ..)` that is going to be executed before hits the `app.use(express.static(..));` where in this middleware we are going to check if the user is allowed to use the protected assets, if he is allowed, then we call the **next function** for letting express continue executing the subsequent middlewares otherwise it is going to send to the user a response saying that he is not allowed to consume the assets.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var path = require('path');

function isUserAllowed(fn) {
  fn(null, false);
}

app.use('/protected/*', function(req, res, next) {
  isUserAllowed(function(err, allowed) {
    if (!allowed) {
      res.status(401).send('You are not allowed to see this page.');
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.listen(4000, function() {
  console.log('server up and running');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can simply prioritize the desired routes by placing them above the middleware `express.static`. Example :

```
app.all("/app",multipart,function(req, res, next){
    console.log("Checking if the user is logged");
    next(); // or end the request ? 
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'),{}));
```